# page not found error on multi language laravel

Tags: laravel

i am using localization on my website. the localization is correctly working on one page. when we are redirecting to some other page the page is loading with the language that we selected on the previous page. and we are changing the language on the current page i got an error " page not found ". Why this error is loading.

here the url is changing to http://127.0.0.1:8000/localisation/lang/mal. i need http://127.0.0.1:8000/localisation/create

layout.mainaster.blade.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div style="background-color: #f8f9fa;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light container">
            <a href="https://www.mynotepaper.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/hHZjfUq.png"
                                                                        width="140px;"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
                    aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @php $locale = session()->get('locale'); @endphp
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                            @switch($locale)
                                @case('us')
                                <img src="{{asset('img/us.png')}}"> English
                                @break
                                @case('mal')
                                 Mlayalam
                                @break
                                @case('in')
                                 Hindi
                                @break
                                @default
                                 English
                            @endswitch
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="lang/en"> English</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="lang/mal"> Mlayalam</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="lang/in"> Hindi</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
use App\Localization;

class LocalizationController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index1($locale)
    {
        App::setLocale($locale);
        // store the locale in session so that the middleware can register it
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data=Localization::get();
        return view('localisation.index',[
            'localizationdata' =>$data
        ]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('localisation.create');
    }
}
?>
```

model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Localization extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes;

     protected $table = 'demo';
     protected $primaryKey = 'id';

     public $timestamps = true;

     protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.mainmaster')
@section('content')


           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">
                   
                  <form role="form" action="{{action('LocalizationController@store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}      
                     <!-- START card-->
                     <div class="card card-default">
                        <div class="card-header">
                           <div class="card-title">Create</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="card-body">
                           <fieldset>
                               <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('create.name')}}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="name" placeholder="{{ __('create.name')}}">
          
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif 
                            </div>
                           </fieldset>
                           <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('create.ph')}}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="ph" placeholder="{{ __('create.ph')}}">
          
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('ph'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('ph') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif 
                            </div>
                           </fieldset>
                           <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('create.address')}}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="address" placeholder="{{ __('create.address')}}">
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('address'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif 
                            </div>
                           </fieldset>
                           <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('create.email')}}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="email" placeholder="{{ __('create.email')}}">
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif 
                            </div>
                           </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center"><button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="submit">Create</button>
                        </div>
                     </div><!-- END card-->
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div><!-- END row-->


@endsection
```

middlewear:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use App;
use Closure;

class Localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'LocalizationController@index1');
Route::resource('localisation','LocalizationController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late for this response but may help someone else. Just need to change your route and update your view.

In your routes, update your route to:

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', ['as' => 'lang.locale', 'uses' => 'LocalizationController@index1']);
```

In your view you need to change to update the route to actually engage the controller.

So in view update it to;

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route ('lang.locale', 'en') }}"> English</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route ('lang.locale', 'mal') }}"> Mlayalam</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route ('lang.locale', 'in') }}"> Hindi</a>
</div>
```